# VB.net Search Query using two parameters

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, datasource

I have created a search query in VB.net using datasource which has two parameters.

```
SELECT        [Product Code], Description, Input_Date, Price, Unit, Quantity, Markup, Total
FROM            Inventory_Table
WHERE        (? = ?)
```

I made two parameters because I want to search by specific columns, this is how i used the query:

```
  Inventory_TableTableAdapter.SearchQuery(DBDataSet1.Inventory_Table, InvSearchCombo.Text, InvSearchTxt.Text)
```

First parameter would be a dropdown combobox containing all columns from the table, the second parameter would be an input textbox.

But whenever i try searching nothing would appear.
What seems to be the problem? I really want to implement this kind of search feature. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't set the field name as parameter. You should have to create a dinamic sql instead. Parsing the string

Comment: does it mean i need to make separate queries per field name?

Comment: Your tittle is not according with your explanation, I mean, your tittle, could be VB.net Search Query using dynamic attritube in where clause or something like this.

Comment: @MarcIntes, did you find your answer?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this you can use a dynamic code

```
Dim columnQuery As String = "Description"

Using command As New SqlCommand( "select Description,Input_Date from dep where " &  columnQuery  & " = @par1", connection)

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par1", "descripcion")

End using
```

**EDIT**

A better form could be this:

First, create store procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_LIST_TABLA_BY_DYNAMIC_COLUMN
@PAR_COLUMN VARCHAR(20),
@PAR_VALUE VARCHAR(20)
AS

DECLARE @STRSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @STRSQL  = 'SELECT PRODUCT_CODE,DESCRIP,INPUT_DATE FROM INVENTORY_TABLE WHERE ' + @PAR_COLUMN + ' = ' + @PAR_VALUE

EXEC sp_executesql @STRSQL
```

Then invoke it:

```
Using command As New SqlCommand( "SP_LIST_TABLA_BY_DYNAMIC_COLUMN", connection)
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PAR_COLUMN", "product_code")
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PAR_VALUE", "1")

    Using reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read() 


    End While
    End using

End using
```

**But like user @Basic says: if the column name is coming from user input (even if via a database) then you're going to be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks**

One suggestion could be evaluate that par_column name exists and par_value don't have some special characters.

Comment: But be aware that if the column name is coming from user input (even if via a database) then you're going to be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Eg Imagine if the column name entered was `1=1; DROP TABLE dep;--` (Obviously don't do this)

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a combo filter and save the `ID` as `@par1` and text field save as `@par2`

Combo have this values:

- none  (id: -999)
- field1 (id: 0)
- field2 (id: 1)

> Not sure about how you set your parameter so I will use some pseudo code.

You can make a trick to dynamic set what filter to use.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Inventory_Table
WHERE        
    (Field1 = @par2 and 0 = @par1)
OR  (Field2 = @par2 and 1 = @par1)
OR  (-999 = @par1)
```

So if you select `Field1` then `0 = @par1` will be true and first filter will be active

if you select `Field2` then `1 = @par1` will be true and second filter will be active

if `none` is select all rows are return.

Comment: His question is more about dynamic attribute as parameter, his tittle is not according with his explanation.

Comment: Hola @JuanRuizdeCastilla, Not sure if doesnt match the title, but match the requirement on the text. He want choose the `fieldName` from a combobox, and filter on that `fieldName`

Comment: Hi namesake :), Are you sure?, he talk about dynamic attribute in where clause independently if are two parameters nested.

Comment: Tocayo Juan Im 95% sure. Not see any mention on OP question to dynamic attribute. I have see this kind of question before. Is just a search in the table. The problem is the field is choose from the combobox. I think my solution will help.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza OP doesn't mention dynamic column names because he doesn't know that's what he needs (apparently). According to the question and his sample code, he needs the first parameter to be the column where to search and the second parameter the value to search for.

Comment: @JoshPart I know that, dont you think my answer solve that case? Or maybe i need to explain more detail?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yes and no; it is a way to solve it but he will require his query to have all Field names specified in the `WHERE` clause. The more fields the table has, the more hideous the query would look (and I think it will hit performance too, but I'm not really sure of that). I belive the best solution is between dynamic query and filtering client-side

Comment: Apologize @JuanCarlosOropeza, your solutions works, is a little weirdo but it works, and prevent sql inject right?

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla Is ok. In my comment I first suggest the dinamic sql, Maybe my format is too complicated for this simple issue :). But I belive have some uses.

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla Yes, this version prevent sql inject :) I would use it as your version, inside a store procedure.